# Method for site wide authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth

I am currently looking for a method to provide site wide authentication, for services exposed to the cloud, on the site I am responsible for. Some services are a Python based, some in PHP and some in Perl. Individual services would need to be able to get access to the user profile and the associated roles.

On the main page users are logged in and a cookie is created using a JWT token. The main site is using NodeJS for the auth system and is built in-house.

At this point I am wondering whether we should use OAuth2 across the site or whether there is another approach that may be simpler, where we don’t need to deal with inter domain requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're currently investigating is the re-use of a JWT as an authentication token across multiple services. Although it's technically possible - it is not the ideal secure approach.

The most secure approach is for separation of application contexts, whereby each application should be tied to a different application credential (in OAuth2 terms). This is ensures that the user receives a credential unique to that application, allows the credentials to be managed/revoked separately and audited in isolation.

To implement this smoothly for UI flows requires an identity provider that supports SSO, and also assumes that each UI application can handle negotiation to the IDP to access that SSO session.

For interactions that are system to system authenticated, eg. Python, you would need to use system to system authentication (OAuth2 client credentials) that again have its own credential. In the case where you need access to the end-user's profile, a management api key (or similar) would be required.